# How to debug JavaScript code in IE F12 console?

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging, console

I am using IE9. I really like F12 debug console. I can input JavaScript code to try out without creating a file and loading it by a server.

However, I cannot set a breakpoint on the piece of code in console. What should I do?

Comment: Stating the obvious: it won't debug JavaScript until you press the "Start Debugging" button.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure debugging has been started (Script->Start Debugging) then you can use the debugger keyword which will cause the debugger to break.

```
var x = 0;
debugger;
x++;
```